# Energy Efficiency Task Scheduling in Cloud Computing

Tags: cloud, task, scheduling, energy

My name is Umer and I am MS Student... My thesis work starts now... I am trying to find the problem statement...

I want to ask that Dr give me a task that less energy consumes in task scheduling. Read paper related to this...

Energy consumes data center. the data center contains a lot of servers. 
How energy efficiency can be optimal in task scheduling because energy consumes in the data center? 
How task scheduling consumes energy?
How can I find energy efficiency in task scheduling?

Every comment will be appreciated. please guide me. I am very thankful to you.

Comment: to get a good answer, could you please more specific?

Comment: actually i want to ask how can i measure energy efficiency consume in task scheduling in cloud computing